# Can modulo(remainder) be distribute over division?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Let $a\%b$ be the modulo operation, returning the remainder of $a$ when divided by $b$. Is it true that:
$$\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)\% 5 = \frac{(a\% 5)}{(b\% 5)}$$

For instance, for $a=10$ and $b=2$ we have

$$\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)\%5=5\%5=0$$
$$\frac{(a\% 5)}{(b\% 5)}=\frac{(10\% 5)}{(2\% 5)}=0$$

Is this always true?

Comment: What do you mean by the "modulo" function? It is usually treated as a binary operator, or perhaps a function of two variables. Just what does modulo(a) mean?

Comment: From what I'm seeing in the question, I think you're implying modulo 5. Are you? If so, _mention_ it in your question.

Comment: modulo is remainder function(generally reffered as  % in programming languages).

Comment: @hii, I have provided a counterexample in the answers. :)

Comment: I edited the question; hopefully it will be clearer to other readers now. (I changed the modulo(a,b) notation to a%b, since you were already using both in the question; feel free to change it however you like though)

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample:

Take $a=29$ and $b=27$.